# Cannot resolve symbol 'DatabaseChangeListener'

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea

I'm implementing database listener functionality and for that, I'm using oracle's `DatabaseChangeListener` interface.

I have included the correct dependency to pom.xml

`DatabaseChangeListener` is downloaded and resides in the classpath.

But IntelliJ idea is complaining that `Cannot resolve symbol 'DatabaseChangeListener'`

**Workaround**

1. Clear the cache by File | Invalidate Caches / Restart
2. Delete the .idea and other IntelliJ related files and restart
3. Deleted the entire.m2 folder and reimport

Nothing was helped me.

Appreciate it if anyone helps me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.!!!

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

[image: refer]

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are adding the depency for scope **runtime**.
For JDBC that actually is the norm. Despite many database vendors and their own libraries JDBC kept one single SQL API. The application need not depend on the database used. Simply remove the scope line.

In this case you want to use a vendor specific database listener class.

A bit sad, and listening for changes might trigger too much backcalls.

An alternative for this, could be adding a specific TRIGGERs on INSERTs and such. It could also be querying specific [meta data from the SQL connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html), and polling periodically.

```
DatabaseMetaData metaDate = connection.getMetaData();
```

Comment: I have removed the <scope>runtime</scope>. The issue is resolved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Added some alternatives for people with the same problem.